# How to change message format from MQHRF2 to string format in C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am receiving message in MQHRF2 format in my remote MQ . We are using MISP to send message to remote MQ . My question is how can I change this format MQHRF2 to MQSTR in MQ or Can I change this format MQHRF2 to string format in C# ? Any way it's possible to change message format? please help

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you are asking to cause the sending side to send MQSTR messages or you want the receiving side to receive them as MQSTR messages, both are possible solutions.  I am unsure what MISP is.  If you are getting a MQHRF2 header at all from a C# app it sounds like you are probably using XMS.NET?

Comment: I want the sender side to change message format to MQSTR . But I changed properties into none in subscriptions tab and it worked for me . I posted what I did .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For me this solution worked :**

I use IBM MQ Explorer to connect to remote MQ . I was receiving message as MQHRF2 format into my remote MQ but I want MQSTR format . It's easier to extract MQSTR message .

**Solution**

connect to your remote MQ then go to 
subscriptions -> go to your MQ -> properties -> in general tab -> change properties to none .

Voila!! it worked for me :) . By default message format is MQSTR . So, if we change MQHRF2 to none then it'll be changed into MQSTR .

Answer (score 0):

How does MISP connect and open the MQ queue?  Do you use MQ JNDI to hold the connection information?  Because if you can set the "targetClient" to MQ in the MQ JNDI then problem solved.

"MQ" means deliver only the payload to the target application (the properties are stripped from the message).

Or you can do it in the code:

```
inQ = session.createQueue("queue://MQWT1/TEST.Q1?targetClient=1");
```

or

```
inQ.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

or

```
<config-property name="targetClient">MQ</config-property>
```

---

Update:

You can try forcing the MQGET to deliver the message with Named Properties (message properties) and then just ignore them.  The message MQMD.format field will be MQSTR (string) or blank if it wasn't set.

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_PROPERTIES_IN_HANDLE + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
inQ.Get(msg, gmo);
```

Comment: Roger, what is MISP, I have not heard this term before.

Comment: I don't know - I googled it and there is something on GitHub that does Pub/Sub, so I'm guessing that's it

Comment: thanks for reply :) . I changed MQHRF2 to MQSTR format . Process : subscriptions -> go to your queue name  -> properties -> in general tab -> change properties to none . By default MQ format is MQSTR  . So if we change into none then message format will be changed int MQSTR

Comment: I use IBM MQ Explorer .